# How can I get images to stay proportionate when resizing window?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a relatively simple classroom-like site with overlaying images. Basically, there are a bunch of pictures you can interact with that will take you to different websites with different resources. I am struggling immensely with getting the sizing and proportions of all the images correct. I want there to be a background image that stretches to span the entire page and then carefully placed images/text over the background image/other images. As you can tell, when resizing the JSFiddle, everything gets disproportionate.

A more concrete example of what I'm trying to do: You can see the text over the "chalkboard" image. I want it to appear as if the text is writing on the chalkboard so it shouldn't be moving off the blackboard when resizing the window or looking at it through different aspect ratios. I'm trying to do this with lots and lots of images so a thorough explanation would be most helpful.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4r5z38Lc/1/)

```css
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(71, 71, 71);
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0.75;
}

a {
  color: lightgray;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Schoolbell', arial, serif;
  color: white;
}

.container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1630699376059-b781970715b1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}

#whiteboard img {
  width: 40%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 35%;
}

#chalkboard img {
  width: 20%;
  height: 40%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2%;
  left: 78%;
}

#chalkboard p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 80%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 140%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="whiteboard"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1497409988347-cbfaac2f0b12?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80" /></div>
    <div id="chalkboard">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1614292253351-4deb4913c142?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80" />
      <p>
        Hi all!
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <p>Footer Stuff</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

// Side Note: These aren't the images I'm trying to use, just stock photo examples.

Thank you!

Comment: Do not position your images as absolute ignoring the parents. very bad praxis. Position the parents (the containers of the images) and then use for the images (look for it and you'll learn it better) "object-fit" properties. You will have less problems with your text. Finally as a background image, don't use background-cover:100% use "cover" property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already have the positioning done in terms of % of the actual picture I think all you basically need to do is make sure that that picture's container maintains the same aspect ratio whatever the viewport aspect ratio is.

I did a rough look at your webp image and converted it to a png and took the dimensions - you will probably want to refine that to be more accurate.

Here is the snippet:

```html
<style>
  .footer {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(71, 71, 71);
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0.75;
  }
  
  a {
    color: lightgray;
  }
  
  p {
    font-family: 'Schoolbell', arial, serif;
    color: white;
  }
  
  .container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    /*height: 100%;*/
    width: 100%;
    aspect-ratio: 873 / 579;
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJHjE.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;
  }
  
  #whiteboard img {
    width: 40%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 35%;
  }
  
  #chalkboard img {
    width: 20%;
    height: 40%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2%;
    left: 78%;
  }
  
  #chalkboard p {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left: 80%;
    color: white;
    font-size: 140%;
    text-align: center;
  }
</style>
<html>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="whiteboard"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1497409988347-cbfaac2f0b12?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80" /></div>
    <div id="chalkboard">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1614292253351-4deb4913c142?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80" />
      <p>
        Hi all!
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <p>Footer Stuff</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Note: you will need to decide what to do about the writing - the font-size also needs to be defined in relative terms so it shrinks appropriately.

ADDITION: It's been pointed out that keeping the width always at 100vw causes cropping of the image.

Here is a snippet which 'decides' whether to make the width or the height of the classroom as much as it can be (100vw or 100vh) and adjusts the other dimension so the aspect ratio is always maintained.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .footer {
      position: fixed;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: rgb(71, 71, 71);
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      opacity: 0.75;
    }
    
    a {
      color: lightgray;
    }
    
    p {
      font-family: 'Schoolbell', arial, serif;
      color: white;
    }
    
    .container {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0%;
      left: 0%;
      aspect-ratio: 873 / 579;
      background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJHjE.png");
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: 100% auto;
    }
    
    @media (min-aspect-ratio: 873/579) {
      .container {
        height: 100vh;
      }
    }
    
    @media (max-aspect-ratio: 873/579) {
      .container {
        width: 100vw;
      }
    }
    
    #whiteboard img {
      width: 40%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 20%;
      left: 35%;
    }
    
    #chalkboard img {
      width: 20%;
      height: 40%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 2%;
      left: 78%;
    }
    
    #chalkboard p {
      position: absolute;
      top: 10%;
      left: 80%;
      color: white;
      font-size: 140%;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="whiteboard"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1497409988347-cbfaac2f0b12?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80" /></div>
    <div id="chalkboard">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1614292253351-4deb4913c142?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80" />
      <p>
        Hi all!
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <p>Footer Stuff</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This answer is great when resizing width, but **not for height!** , as well as if I set width to very high then **bottom parts of a background image is cropped**

Comment: I must have misunderstood what you wanted. I thought you always wanted the classroom image to fill the viewport width-wise. Are you saying you want the whole image to be always wholly contained within the viewport?

Comment: But it's not my question even! , I hope the question asker will clarify what is needed(width-wise/both width & height)

Comment: @Neptotech-vishnu Whoops1 Sorry I didn't check who had commented. Yes you are quite right and I've added another snippet which uses either full width or full height as appropriate depending on the aspect ratios.